# How to prevent the file browser from showing folders before files?

Tags: interface, file-browser

I've set my file browser to sort by Modified Date, but it always shows all of my folders (sorted by date)  before any files (sorted by date). So when I want to choose a file, which is the whole purpose of the dialog, I always have to scroll past all the folders.

Is there any way to get the file browser to intermingle files and folders, sorted by date?

Bonus question: is there any way to permanently move the Volumes and System lists to the bottom of the file browser's left panel?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there currently is no way to sort folders mixed with files.
As a workaround you can temporarily hide all folders from view.

Open the filters popover, then from the file types untick the *Folders* entry.

[image]